# Zend Framework - How do to preDispatch for all controllers?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I cant load this plugin how can i load this?

I have IndexController.php and I have OthersController.php. For all those controllers, to have 1 single preDispatch method i wrote a plugin as following. Can you please guide me kindly, how i can now attach this with all other controllers???

@file: application/controllers/GlobalControllerPlugin.php

```
class GlobalControllerPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract 
{ 

  public function preDispatch() 
  {
     $this->view->helloworld = 
          '(from preDispatch)--->(controllers)--->(views)--->yesGreat)';

  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add (register) the plugin to the front controller.

Either in the `Bootstrap.php`,

```
public function _initGlobalPlugin() {

    $this->bootstrap('frontController');

    // require_once 'GlobalControllerPlugin.php';
    $plugin = new GlobalControllerPlugin();

    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->registerPlugin($plugin);

    return $plugin;
}
```

or in the `application.ini`:

```
resources.frontController.plugins.global = "Global_Controller_Plugin_Common"
```

Make sure, you configured autoloader properly to load namespace you use.